# Cannot change the value of global variable in Python

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I have a function that I want to count how many times it is called (and save a image with that counter value as its name). I made a global function called `counter` . But if I do `counter = counter+1`. It says `Unresolved reference`. Am I missing something ?

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
counter = 0
def saveImage(img):
    counter = counter+1

    imgs = str(counter) + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite('images/'+imgs, img)
```

Comment: add `global counter` inside your function before assigning value to it .

Comment: [use of global keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
counter = 0
def saveImage(img):
    global counter  # to modify global variable, you need to explicitly declare so... 
    counter = counter+1

    imgs = str(counter) + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite('images/'+imgs, img)
```